# SSH over internet. Connection time out

Tags: ssh, connection, internet

This question seems to come up a lot, but none of the answers seem to work for me. I'm trying to connect to my RPi over the internet, but when I try to connect over the internet (with putty) using a dynamic dns it get a `Network error: Connection timed out.`

I've done the following steps:

1. I assigned a static IP to my RPi. I tested this with a reboot of both my router and my pi and checked with `ifconfig` each time. I can SSH through my LAN just fine so the issue is definitely not here.
2. I created a hostname on no-ip and setup a script to update the hostname when it changes. The hostname's IP corresponds with my router's IP. I'm not sure if the auto-update works but that's another issue.
3. I setup a port forward from my router (source port 22322) to my RPi's static IP (destination port 22). I used http://canyouseeme.org/ to confirm if the port's open and it says it's successfull.
4. I added a rule to iptables to allow the traffic, `iptables -L` returns the following:

   ```
   root@foxypi:/home/pi# iptables -L
   Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh

   Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination

   Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination
   ```
5. In `/etc/sysctl.conf` I uncommented the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

From what I've read this should allow me to SSH into my RPi, but it just won't work and I'm stumped. Did I miss a crucial step?

Comment: Steps 4 and 5 are not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I made an incredibly simple oversight. Turns out my router doesn't support NAT loopback so when I tried to connect over internet while I'm on the LAN network it didn't work. I just tried again from a public wifi and it works without a hitch.

For those who have the same issue, try connecting from a machine that's not connected on the same LAN as the RPi.

Comment: You could still connect on your home network using the Pi's internal/private IP.

Comment: Oh yea, I could connect using my local IP just fine on my LAN. It's just that I didn't think of testing my internet connection outside of my LAN.